# Need a regex that would allow only numbers and semicolons in a string.

Tags: regex

I need a Regex that would only numbers and semicolon in the String. I have tried a few websites but because of my poor knowledge in Regex I was not able to understand much of it.

Comment: Based on what you are asking, simply `[\d;]+` would suffice.

Comment: What is your environment (perl, JS, bash, C#, VIM, etc...?)

Comment: Regex looks intimidating, but it's honestly not bad with a bit of practice. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for basics and try http://www.debuggex.com for a bit of visualization

Comment: @DylanMadisetti Thanks a lot, I will definitely study the links that you have provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare `[\d;]+` with the original string to make sure they are equal.

Comment: The string name is data and when i match it with the expression that you gave it always returns false.
This is how I have written it: boolean f=data.matches("[\d;]+");

Comment: Your language would help, although I personally may not be able to.

Comment: I am trying to do this in Java

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that fails? I don't know Java but I do know JavaScript and they sure are similar.

Comment: 12;23;43;56;76 This is the String. 
I am storing it in data so data="12;23;43;56;76"
Now when I write boolean f=data.matches("[\\d;]+") it always returns false.

Comment: I wouldn't say Javascript and Java are similar, but their Regexes don't differ much

Comment: @tenub It was actually double slashes that my IDE needs. But your solution works fine on Eclipse. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was starting to scratch my head in wonder. :) Good to know it worked out!

Comment: @DylanMadisetti Thanks a lot for your help as well. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The initial sentence is ambiguous: "I need a Regex that would only numbers and semicolon in the String"

Would *what*?

- Do you want to match only numbers and semicolons?
- Do you want to exclude only numbers and semicolons?
- Do you consider it a match if the string contains a number OR a semicolon, or do you require both to be present?
- If you require both, can they be separated by other characters?

All those cases would have different regexes.

Comment: I want the string to contain only numbers and semicolons otherwise return false.

Comment: So you want numbers and semicolons to be present at the same time? Can the strings include alphabet or other characters? As I said, depending on what your input strings are, and what you want to do, the regexes can be quite different. Please define the problem, with examples. The solution you have been given, testing for [\d;]+ will match any string that has EITHER a number OR a semicolon, and will also match strings that have anything else with a number OR a semicolon, but that regex doesn't require both to be present.